# Localized resources not loaded in static context

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization, resources

I have two resource files defined in my application:

```
Resources.resx
Resources.de.resx
```

When the application starts, I set the current thread and thread UI culture to a `CultureInfo` for *de* (*German*). For testing purposes, I access the resource directly after the thread culture has been set using `Resources.MyResource` and as expected, the resource is *German* (e.g. the correct localized resource entry has been loaded).

At some later point in the application, *still on the UI thread*, I access the resources again in a static context, which looks like this:

```
[Export]
public static readonly MenuItem MyMenuItem = new MenuItem(Resources.MyResource);
```

However here, the resource is suddenly *English* (fallback) again!

I made sure that:

- Both resource files are available.
- The *German* resource can be loaded.
- The thread culture and thread UI culture are set only once.
- The resource (which fails) is accessed from the same thread as when accessing it the first time (for testing).
- The resource (which fails) is loaded AFTER the thread culture has been set.

Comment: How about making MyMenuItem a static property with a getter that creates the MenuItem when it's called (the first time)?

Comment: @Clemens I don't follow? MyMenuItem is an instance of MenuItem which is being exported as a MEF component (hence the export). And MenuItem is not the same as a WPF menu item, if that caused some confusion.

Comment: Not sure about the Export thing, but my idea was to create the MenuItem as late as possible by implementing a static property getter that won't create the MenuItem before it's actually accessed.